# How to prevent grep from breaking up lines in a ksh script?

Tags: unix, scripting, grep, ksh

I'm trying to modify a ksh script to print out the line that contains the phrase "/var/corefiles" . I'm fairly new to scripting, so this has me buggered. For example, if I have the following line in a file

```
/dev/x /dev/x2 /var/corefiles yes
```

And I use this for loop:

```
for $host in $(grep "var/corefiles" $VFSTAB_LOC); do
         echo $i
done
```

It outputs:

```
 /dev/x
 /dev/x2
 /var/corefiles
 yes
```

I'm a little confused as to why it only prints out one chunk at a time. If anyone has any explanations/modifications they would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply doing `grep "var/corefiles" $VFSTAB_LOC` (without the `for` or `echo`) will do exactly what you say you're wanting to do.

Comment: I have a feeling that the 'echo' is merely a reduced demo of what he really does in the loop :)

Comment: I 'suffer' GIGO even without trying. I do try to apply common some artificial (?) intelligence though

Comment: Man I'm dumb. Thanks! Any yes, echo was a placeholder for everything else going on :)

Answer (score 0):

```
grep "var/corefiles" $VFSTAB_LOC | while read line; do
         echo "$line"
done
```

<strike><sub>or in recent bashes</sub></strike>

```
readarray mylines < grep "var/corefiles" $VFSTAB_LOC

for line in "${mylines[@]}"; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: I suppose I do _now_ :) The first option _does_ work with the Korn shell, IIRC